# making buttons with the same spacing by giving Autolayout constraints

Tags: swift, xcode

I gave constraints to the buttons. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHhY9.png)

Hello, I was working my app on iPhone 11 Pro max in the storyboard, and when I runt it on (iPad 7 Generation), It has much more spacing between the last button and the leading side of the view.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBwLf.png)

So, I gave the trailing space to the container, and it looked this in the storyboard
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATihM.png)

on the iPad 7generation simulator, it looked this way.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uitkb.png)

it's got much more spacing between the 3rd button and the last button. How can I make the buttons align with the same spacing?

Comment: Try a horizontal `StackView` you can arrange buttons inside it more easily

Answer (score 0):

The StackView suggested by Steve is a nice solution. Or try the snippet below if you want to make it work without a StackView.

To evenly spread buttons horizontally across the screen use the following, an example for 3 buttons:

`"H:|[spacer0(>=0)][button0][spacer1(==spacer0)][button1(==button0)][spacer2(==spacer0)][button2(==button0)][spacer3(==spacer0)]|"`